# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord query using a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model and the user has a relationship which is has_many pets. I want to be able to write an ActiveRecord query where I can select all users with a pet that doesn't have a pet.name of "fluffy"

What's the most efficient way to write this using ActiveRecord? Using straight SQL it would look something such as the following:

`select id from users INNER JOIN pets ON u.id = pets.user_id WHERE pets.name != "fluffy"`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This should work:

```
User.joins(:pets).where("pets.name != 'fluffy'")
```

Also you might want to read the [following part](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) (on `joins`) on the official RoR guidelines.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't it be 'User.joins(:pet)...' - singular - for the symbol parameter?

Comment: @jeffdill2 That depends on how the association is defined. If User `has_one :pet`, for instance, you would be right.

Answer (score 75):

In rails 4 you can make this even more clear:

```
User.joins(:pets).where.not(pets: { name: 'fluffy' })
```

Answer (score 25):

The cleanest way without SQL injection vulnerability is using query parameters:

```
User.joins(:pets).where("pets.name != ?", "fluffy")
```

Some database drivers will utilize prepared statements for above to reuse database query plan. In such case the database doesn't have to analyze query again when only param value varies.