# ActiveRecord find with joins and associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model TwitterUser that has_one website as shown in the model below:

```
class TwitterUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :website, :foreign_key => :id, :primary_key => :website_id
end
```

I'm trying to run a query that will join TwitterUser with Website and get all TwitterUsers' with a website that has an updated_at date > a certain date, limited to 10 rows.

I thought this would give me what I wanted, but apparently it's not. What's wrong with it?

```
TwitterUser.includes().find(:all, :limit => 10, :conditions => ["websites.updated_at >= '2013-05-12 05:31:53.68059'"], :joins => :website)
```

In my database, my twitter_users table consist of a website_id field.
My websites table has an id field.

Comment: Your association sounds like it should be a belongs_to, not a has_one

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10391266/12484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
TwitterUser.joins(:website).where("websites.updated_at >= '2013-05-12 05:31:53.68059'").limit(10)
```