# Reduce two SQL queries to one in activerecord maybe using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Two models User and Article have a relation as:

- User    *has_one*     Article
- Article *belongs_to*  User

-User has a field called 'status'

-Article has a field called 'thing_i_need'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article, foreign_key: request_id
  # status :integer
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: request_id
  # thing_i_need :string
end
```

Query: `User.where(status: 'xyz').last.article.thing_i_need`

Currently, two queries are fired to get the 'thing_i_need'

Any way to do it in one query ?

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391266/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-query-using-a-join) help ?

Comment: try like `Article.includes(:user).where(:users => {:status => 'xyz' }).last. thing_i_need`

Comment: i don't think so it fires joins query. what is `thing_i_need ` can you put you model structure here

Comment: @VishalJAIN Updated question with models. Sorry didn't mention the foreign key.

Comment: still i think same query will work. above query ll not fire 2 queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
User.joins(:article).where(status: 'xyz').pluck('articles.thing_i_need').last
```

I'd recommend reading [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) & [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) query methods from the doc, earlier I was trying select in place of pluck and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Article.includes('user').where('users.status = ? and articals.request_id = users.request_id', 'xyz').first.thing_i_need
```

Comment: Updated question with models. Sorry didn't mention the foreign key

Comment: Unknown column 'users.status' in 'where clause': SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles`  WHERE (users.status = 'xyz' and articles.request_id = users.request_id)  ORDER BY `articles`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.status' in 'where clause': SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles`  WHERE (users.status = 'xyz' and articles.request_id = users.request_id)  ORDER BY `articles`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

You may use user joins

```
Article.find(
    :all,
    :joins => :users,
    :conditions => {
        :users => {
            :status => 'xyz'
        }
    }
).last.thing_i_need
```

Comment: Updated question with models. Sorry didn't mention the foreign key

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Articles with 'id': (all, {:joins=>:users, :conditions=>{:users=>{:status=>"xyz"}}}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)