# Getting count of number of 'base' records after query with join

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Imagine in ActiveRecord (pseudo code)

```
Person has_many books
Book belongs_to person
```

Let's say there are three persons and 6 fiction books.

```
results = Person.joins(:books).fiction  # fiction is a scope name
results.count # would be 6, number of fiction books
```

The question is, how do I get the total number **Person** objects in the result, not the number of **books**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per docs http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins, the above method should be returning person's array. Fiction scope may contain code like books.type = 'fiction' which makes LEFT JOIN query on books resulting in repetitive person's.

You can simply do

```
results = Person.joins(:books).fiction
results.uniq.count
```

to get the person count

Similar question to follow [Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord query using a join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391266/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-query-using-a-join)

Comment: Thanks!  didn't see that when I RTFM'd.